# Erasing a tuple from a set with tuple and custom sort function

Tags: c++, set, erase, emplace

How can we remove elements from a set like below which has iterator as part of its key? .erase() throws error saying ***no matching member function for call to 'erase'***. Just like emplace() can be used for inserting tuples, what can be used for erasing a tuple from a set instead of directly providing iterator?

```
list<int> v;

static constexpr auto cmp = [](pair<int, list<int>::iterator > a, pair<int, list<int>::iterator > b)
{
    return a.first < b.first;
};
set< pair<int, list<int>::iterator >, decltype(cmp) > Set{cmp};
v.push_back(1);
Set.emplace( 1, v.rbegin() ); //  Works
Set.erase( make_pair(1, v.rbegin() ) ); // Throws error
```

Error

```
Line 23: Char 13: error: no matching member function for call to 'erase' Set.erase( make_pair(val, v.rbegin() ) ); ~~~~^~~~~ /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/stl_set.h:654:7: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'pair<typename __decay_and_strip<int &>::__type, typename __decay_and_strip<reverse_iterator<_List_iterator<int>>>::__type>' (aka 'pair<int, std::reverse_iterator<std::_List_iterator<int>>>') to 'std::set<std::pair<int, std::_List_iterator<int>>, const MaxStack::(lambda at prog_joined.cpp:10:33), std::allocator<std::pair<int, std::_List_iterator<int>>>>::const_iterator' (aka '_Rb_tree_const_iterator<std::pair<int, std::_List_iterator<int>>>') for 1st argument erase(const_iterator __position) ^ /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/stl_set.h:684:7: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'pair<[...], typename __decay_and_strip<reverse_iterator<_List_iterator<int>>>::__type>' to 'const pair<[...], std::_List_iterator<int>>' for 1st argument erase(const key_type& __x) ^ /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/stl_set.h:706:7: note: candidate function not viable: requires 2 arguments, but 1 was provided erase(const_iterator __first, const_iterator __last) ^
```

Context :
I am trying to create a datastructure where I receive a stream of elements and I need to store the order of the stream as well as be able to retrieve or erase the maximum element at any point.

Comment: There is no overloaded function for `erase` which accepts a `tuple`. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/erase

Comment: Did you mean `make_pair` rather than `make_tuple`?

Comment: Yeah, _make_pair_ but it doesn't make a difference, it throws same error. Edited

Comment: What is the *full* error message? Doesn't it tell you which overloads are there? In any case, you specified a list iterator as part of the pair but you pass a list reverse iterator.

Comment: Edited now with complete error

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this code is that your pair uses `list::iterator` but you try initializing it with `rbegin()` which returns objects of type `reverse_iterator`. Here is the [consistent version](https://godbolt.org/z/nT4xeoYbr) that compiles.

Having said that, I suggest adding some context to the question and maybe we can suggest a simpler solution that will not require navigating through template complexities.

Comment: Added the context, hope it helps. Please suggest if you have better ideas of achieving it. Thanks.

Comment: what does it mean "store the order of the stream" ? In any case, please accept my answer if it fixed your compilation problem.